# docker registry-mirrors is not used for fqdn images

Tags: docker, mirroring, mirror, docker-registry

I have a docker server behind a firewall, so I cannot pull images directrly from any registry besides internal servers.

I have configured **two** registry mirrors (`registry-1.docker.io` and `mcr.microsoft.com`), following [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/).

My `daemon.json` looks like:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [
          "https://registry_1_docker_io.example.com",
          "https://mcr_microsoft_com.example.com"
  ] 
}
```

I can successfully pull images from docker hub by executing i.e:

```
$ docker pull nginx:1
1: Pulling from library/nginx
....
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:1
```

My problem is that **I cannot pull images from microsoft registry**:

```
# docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

The docker tries to connect directly to `mcr` and ignores my mirror. If I use short image name (`mssql/server:2017-latest` instead of `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`) it works, but it might get the image from docker hub instead of microsoft's mcr if the tag is the same on both.

Additionally, If I look at logs, docker tries all proxies for the image in order, so there might be a situation when image is fetched from wrong repository.

**Is there any way to mark a mirror as a mirror for specific registry?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to mark a mirror as a mirror for specific registry?

No, this is a limitation of the docker engine, `registry-mirrors` is only for Docker Hub. You can follow [issue 18818](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18818) for more details.

This may change when docker swaps out the image handling from docker to containerd in the near future, since containerd has a different configuration for handling mirrors.